# Check span attribute contains text in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Just wandering, will it be possible to check span attribute contains text in Jquery?

Example:
I have the following html code:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="user-name">
     <span class="user_title">Mrs Support</span>
     <span class="org_name" org-full-name="Test">Moon Company</span>
     <span><a class="mutual">3 mutual user</a></span></div>
</div>
```

I want to find out attribute org-full-name value contains "es" .

I tried the following code, but it's not working

```
$("#test").find(".user-name:icontains('es')")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an alternative approach, but you can use `.indexOf`.It will return true or False based on the text

```js
console.log($("#test span[org-full-name=Test]").text().indexOf("es")>=0)


//alternate way to have the text based approach
console.log($("#test span[org-full-name]").text().indexOf("es")>=0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <div class="user-name">
     <span class="user_title">Mrs Support</span>
     <span class="org_name" org-full-name="Test">Test</span>
     <span><a class="mutual">3 mutual user</a></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the solution been provided is only work when the attribute value and the text are the same. However,  the text and the attribute value (org-full-name) is not always the same.. so any way it can be check based on the attribute value instead?

Comment: @JinYong please see to my edited answer. You need to check against the text isnt ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). A `:contains` selector only works on text, not on attribute values

```js
$("#test .user-name [org-full-name]").filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('org-full-name').toLowerCase().indexOf('es')>-1
}).css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div class="user-name">
    <span class="user_title">Mrs Support</span>
    <span class="org_name" org-full-name="Test">Moon Company</span>
    <span><a class="mutual">3 mutual user</a></span>
  </div>
    <div class="user-name">
    <span class="user_title">Uncle Support</span>
    <span class="org_name" org-full-name="Foo">Howl at Moon</span>
    <span><a class="mutual">9 mutual user</a></span>
  </div>
      <div class="user-name">
    <span class="user_title">Support Junior</span>
    <span class="org_name" org-full-name="Especially">Unemployed</span>
    <span><a class="mutual">9 mutual user</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it like this:

```
$("#test .org_name").attr("org-full-name").indexOf("es") > 0
```

This will return true if "es" is contained inside the attribute's value or false otherwise.

Comment: This will always pull that attribute value from first element matching the selector in the page

Comment: he didn't specify in his question that he need to check every matching attribute in the page, this should be good enough for the question.

Comment: Just pointing out it fails when more than one of that class exist